# My Macbook Pro Right Speaker Kept Going Broken Even After Replacement

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, speakers

The right speaker of my macbook pro retina 13" kept going broken even after I replaced the speaker. (Ran out of the warranty at this point so had to DIY, also no Apple Store near me, have to fly to one if need be). A while ago the right speaker starts to produce cracking sounds so I ordered a speaker online and replaced it myself. It worked for a while until today it started to produce similar noise again. I can take photos of the inside later today. I wonder if any of you might know how this malfunctioning appeared. I suspect it might be a software + hardware problem (meaning a software malfunction results at the speaker getting broken) but I might be wrong. Could it be overheating? It is really hot lately.

Comment: It's definitely a software issue.

Comment: @Peanut it could be. But how come the new speaker performed normal for about 20 days?

Comment: Here's how to test whether it's hardware or software - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191511/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin I've read it 30 days ago. According to this method it was a hardware issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well known issue of macbook pro since 2009 and it effects even the latest model. The reason being the macbook speakers are not designed to resist heat. If it has been working for hours over 100 degree (or 30 some celsius idk) the rubber will melt and tear under high volume. The left speaker will less likely to have such condition since the ventilation is better on the left corner. Why does Apple keep using this type of rubber? I guess they want the rubber to be bouncy enough to make decent sound while keep the cost low. Besides Apple products are never built to last anyways. All you can do is to cool your macbook while using it or you can try to use superglue to cover the rubber, which would make it tougher but the sound will be worse. For a quick fix, you can put gel around the rubber or just the place of the torn mark(s). Take a look at this picture. This is how I did it.

[image: How To]

Comment: Man it works the magic. The sound does sound weird after I superglued it.