# Audio & Left side USB fail on Mackbook Air Mid 2013

Tags: audio, usb

Just wondering if anyone has any thoughts on the likely culprit for my mac that has decided to start being a pain in the ass.

Basically, the in-built audio has failed with both sound input and output displaying the "No Output Devices Found" message in the sound preferences screen. At the same time, the left side USB port (as looking at the device, under the magsafe port) also isn't working.

I've tried:

- PRAM/SMC reset
- Trying headphones
- Trying a USB headset (works on right side port, but seems to make the
  mac try to recognise the in-built sound, which causes the whole
  system to crash)
- Doing a complete fresh install of OSX (I know, extreme. And ineffective)

The system is fully updated. But based on the audio and left side USB port both failing, I suspect a hardware problem.

Is it hardware? And if so, any suggestions on a fix other than taking it back to the apple store for expensive fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right speakers malfunction on MacBook Pro Retina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191509/right-speakers-malfunction-on-macbook-pro-retina)

Comment: tbh, I'm not sure it's a duplicate, but my answer there can quickly eliminate hardware/software

Comment: I don't think it's the same issue, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Yeah, I was doubtful myself, after I re-read your post - I left the link in there just in case. If I pull my vote, I think the link may disappear, so let me test & if so I'll re-add it below, just in case it may be of some use to future Googlers.

Comment: Link still there... but just in case it vanishes later - for potential [if not directly-related] audio hardware fail, try this answer - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191509/right-speakers-malfunction-on-macbook-pro-retina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If trying to use the Audio Midi Setup (as suggested in comments by Tetsujin) doesn't help, your next step would be to run Apple Diagnostics.

**Run Apple Diagnostics**

Follow the steps below to run Apple Diagnostics:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>D</kbd> key and **keep it down** until you see the Diagnostics screen appear
4. Wait for Diagnostics to finish (this typically only takes a few minutes)
5. Once complete, one of two things will appear on the screen:

   - a *No issues found* message
   - a brief description of any errors found plus further instructions
6. If the diagnostics test does find errors, take a note of what they are

**Note:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 3 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete. Regardless, take a note of what happens and let me know how you went.

Comment: Looks like it is a hardware problem. Diagnostics advises:
`There may be an issue with the audio hardware
Reference code: VFF001`

Answer (score 0):

So as an update, I never got round to taking the laptop into apple as they advised, and magically after a week or so it sorted itself out and has worked fine since.