# Crackling/Popping Right Speaker on Mid 2015 15" Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, audio, hardware, speakers

[image: screenshot of About Mac: Version 10.14 | MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) | Processor: 2.5 Hz Intel Core i7 | Memory: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3 | Startup Disk: Macintosh HD | Graphics: Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB | (Serial Number is blurred out). Options: System Report | Software Update]

I've only began experiencing this issue this morning, I first noticed it at around 4 AM. Its 1 PM now.

What I've done so far:

- Reset PRAM & SMC
- Switched Left & Right Speakers. The right speaker was consistently the one that popped, which makes me wonder why both the macbook speaker and logitech speaker had the crackling.
- Updated Audio MIDI setup
- Changed the output device (used built in speakers before, & Logitech X-140 2 Piece Speaker Set now). Both had popping.
- Switched format to 2 ch 32 bit Float 44.1 kHz

Usually it'll be 1-2 consecutive pops every 10 minutes or so. It's loud and high pitched - it's about the same pitch as white noise.

It doesn't seem to be related with volume. It doesn't crackle when the volume gets louder, and the crackling isn't at all synced with any peaks of the sound (in which there are barely any, the sound quality otherwise is good). In fact, most of the crackling happens when the volume is quiet, and even when nothing is playing.

I haven't dropped or damaged the MacBook in any way. What can I do to fix this, and if Apple Repair is necessary, how much would it cost? Also, is it still a hardware issue when both the built in speaker and plugged in speaker experienced the same popping?

Comment: Try this to determine hardware or software - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191511/85275

Comment: It **is** possible it's some sort of short in the right analog channel, I suppose. Do you any non-analog audio devices (Bluetooth or TOSLINK speakers, AirPods?) you could try?

Answer (score 0):

Paste following in Terminal:

```
sudo launchctl stop com.apple.audio.coreaudiod && sudo launchctl start com.apple.audio.coreaudiod
```

It helps me.