# Invert polarity of audio output

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, hardware, headphones, mediaplayer

Is it possible to invert the audio output polarity to headphones on MBA M1? If so, how?

I have a music track which seems to have some issue with mastering on the left side of the sounds. I just want to verify that it is indeed a mastering issue & not my headphones going bad on me!

Thanks!

Comment: When you say poliarity - do you mean using a tool like Logic to switch what's in the stereo right channel with what's in the stereo left channel?

Comment: Another pair of headphones/earbuds are the quickest way to test if it is the headphones. Then again, if other audio sounds OK on your headphones, then it is something else. [This site](https://www.audiocheck.net/) has helped me in the past troubleshoot audio problems in AV installations big (theatres) and small (classrooms.)

Comment: I had a similar issue:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/469350/how-can-i-output-balanced-audio-from-my-headphone-jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a lot less soldering to open the file in [Audacity*](https://www.audacityteam.org/download/mac/) [freeware] & reverse the phase of one side of the stereo image - https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/invert.html

Sonically, if both sides were phase-inverted you really wouldn't be able to tell. Ears cannot resolve absolute phase, only relative phase.
If one side is out of phase, then sounds which should appear to be in the centre of the stereo field will appear to be 'somewhere outside your head' in a very odd way. Your brain cannot process such sounds, because they would have to be generated from actually inside your head whilst still being heard through your ears rather than by bone conduction, so the brain rejects it as impossible & instead you perceive the sound as being from a very strange kind of 'everywhere'.

*That's a direct download link, just so it doesn't surprise you. It's perfectly safe.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I'm looking for.
Actually the issue is that left side can is giving some noise/buzzing on initial part of a track while right side isn't!

Comment: That's probably an error in the file itself, not a phase issue.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191511/85275 for how to flip which speaker [or headphone] the sound is sent to. It's a way to eliminate it being a hardware issue - again without soldering.

Comment: Thanks. This is even better. Even with reverse polarity left can has that issue so I've verified that it is either left can of the headphones or my left ear which has, sadly, gone bad! Not sure which would be worse

Comment: Next test - put them in the opposite ears. Cheaper than surgery ;))

Comment: I did exactly that and still the left ear is hearing that noise. I'm hoping that's just over sensivity to sibilance!

Comment: hmmm… next stop, doctor's :/