# Macbook air M1 right speaker stops working until restarted

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, apple-silicon, speakers

I am have been a windows user since I remember. I recently moved to m1 macbooks (air) after the rave reviews. Only problem is my mac’s right side’s speaker sounds distorted for a second and then stops working. Until I restart it.

Please tell me a solution. Because I want to keep the things i am doing and put apple on sleep so i can continue the next day or whatever.

This restarting business is time consuming.

Fyi I already tried reinstalling the OS, stopping coreaudiod and starting again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take it back to the shop where you bought it.

Comment: But is it a software issue or a hardware issue?

Comment: Simple first test for hardware/software issue - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191511/85275 [ignore all the later arguing about 'magnetism' ;)

Comment: Just did,turns out it’s a software problem because crackling is gone. But the speaker stopping persists, only restarting fixes it fora while. Any fixes for that?

Comment: So the affected speaker swaps to the left? In that case, if it's software, you have to start from the very bottom. Start with a new admin account to eliminate things only on your account… then safe boot. If you have any 3rd party audio plugins/routers/effects of any kind, check if they could be responsible, uninstall if necessary.

Comment: Yes, when I move the balance to right. The sound still comes from left. So factory resetting is the key?

Comment: When you change speaker balance, the side you balance away from should go to silence at the extreme. You need to retest with speakers 'normal' then swapped left for right, as in the linked answer. Please report back on what happens in each case.

Comment: I have erased my current macbook settings and reinstalled the OS. :fingers_crossed:

Comment: Hi, brother. I ran a diagnostic test. No problems detected with the audio hardware etc…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out a bad node v14 installation messed up terminal compiler. Reinstalling OS fixed the issue.